# i can not open the app using Android intent plus

Tags: android, flutter

I have an app installed say with id 'com.myname.name'
I am using android_intent_plus to open it from another app as below:

```
bool isInstalled = await DeviceApps.isAppInstalled('com.myname.name');
// isInstalled returns true, so app is already installed and reachable

AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
          action: 'com.myname.name.VIEW',
          // i am using .VIEW just to simplify the request but will replace it later with another action .SAVE 
          package: 'com.myname.name',
          data: 'my name',
          type: 'text/plain'
      );
intent.launch();
```

but it keeps giving error:
Cannot resolve explicit intent, falling back to implicit
Sending intent Intent { act=com.myname.name.VIEW (has extras) }
Failed to handle method call
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.myname.name.VIEW (has extras) }

Sorry but one more question, the opened app designed to reurn STATUS value as string, so how to receive the response from opened app through my intent?

I updated manifest file at  by adding:

```
<intent>
            <action android:name="com.myName.name.SAVE" />
            <data android:scheme="string data" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent>
```

Comment: Include how the target activity is declared in the manifest.

Comment: I am using android_intent_plus package so no need to include target activity in the manifest

Comment: i could reach app details as per action as 'action_application_details_settings'

Comment: *"I am using android_intent_plus package so no need to include target activity in the manifest"* that is, generally, not how Android works; all activities must be declared in the manifest.  From a quick glance at the documentation for that package, it doesn't sound like they're autogenerating them for you either.

Comment: I updated the manifest file, please re-check my above post as i updated it too.
@RyanM

Comment: That is not a valid manifest entry; I'm surprised that even builds (you may want to verify that it's actually being used).  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element for what it should look like.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're seeing means that the app you're trying to open doesn't have the capability to handle the specific request you're making.

In Android, an Intent is basically a message that you can use to request an action from another app. If you're using an explicit intent (i.e., you specify the app package), you need to make sure that the app you're targeting has an Activity that can handle the specific action you're requesting.

In your case, you're using the action 'com.myname.name.VIEW'. This action needs to be declared in the target app's AndroidManifest.xml file, inside the  tag of the corresponding Activity.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myname.name.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you are unable to control the target app's manifest, you will have to use an action that the app can handle or opt for an implicit intent, which means specifying the action and data, but not the package.

Also, to receive a result back from the launched Activity, the typical method in Android is to use startActivityForResult. However, as of Flutter 2.0, the android_intent_plus package does not support receiving results from a launched Activity. You may need to use platform channels to implement this functionality yourself or look for a different package that supports this feature.

Comment: Target app is well configured as it is already being used by others. Actually the problem is  at my code, but i do not know what to do!
Appreciate if you have any suggestions?